# Stack2XML - A JSON to XML Conversion Service

Tags: library

### About

Stack2XML is a web service that fulfills API requests on your behalf and converts the results to XML before returning it to you. The purpose of this service is to support those languages / environments where JSON support hasn't arrived yet or is difficult to implement.

#### License

*Closed source.*

#### Platform

Any platform that can parse XML and make HTTP requests.

#### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Usage:

Stack2XML is designed to be easy to use. Here is an example. Modify:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/questions?comments=true
```

...to...

```
http://stack2xml.quickmediasolutions.com/stackoverflow/questions?comments=true
```

Comment: Would it be better to tag this `library`?

Comment: I gave this some thought for soapi.info, but ultimately dropped it. my reasons may or may not make sense... a request proxy, while ostensibly a good idea, seems to be ripe for abuse. are you sure you want to leverage your ip for requests that you do not generate?

Comment: @code: Hmmm... well I'll think about this. People supply their own API keys so the key issue won't be a problem.

Comment: usage is not measured by key, rather by IP. If you have an app that is using more than the allotted 10k, it must be subjectively evaluated by the gods on high in order to get an increased limit. otherwise you get 86'd. In this case, it will not be 'your' app, but anonymous consumers. i would not be surprised to find language specifically prohibiting proxy services popping up sometime soon.

Comment: @code: Well, it's not going to get a lot of use anyway - most people will just use the API directly.

Comment: quickmediasolutions.com is down :(

Comment: @Smile4ever this app was used very little and was eventually taken down. However, the source code was published here: https://quickmediasolutions.com/pastebin/1/stack2xml-source-code/